# Bootstrap styles not being injected, how to debug

Tags: bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

Recently I upgraded a bunch of dependencies of my project including angular 1.7.1 => 7.1.1, bootstrap 3.4.0 => 4.3.1 and added ng-bootstrap 4.0.1. However, I have noticed that the styles are not being injected (visible-xs, etc). Not exactly how I can debug this.

In angular.json I included the bootstrap styles

```
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "./node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/bootstrap/theme.css",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
              "./themes/main.css"
            ],
```

In app.module.ts I included

```js
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        AppRoutingModule,
        NgbModule,
```

However, somehow I still do not see the styles coming up. Elements that are supposed to be hidden by `visible-xs` is still showing up.

How would I debug this issue?

Comment: It's just that this class doesn't exist. You moved from bootstrap 3.4.0 to 4.3.1. Things have changed. You need to read the documentation. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/migration/#responsive-utilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The visibility classes that were there in v3 have been removed from v4 in favour of using display classes.  This is because the old visibility class always assumed "block" and that's not the case, as some items are "inline", for example.

[Read more here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/migration/#responsive-utilities)